# ¿Como puedo hacer para que aparezca en un ENTRY el 2º dato de una de las columnas de mi tabla?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, linq-to-sql

Ojala puedan ayudarme.
Quiero que en un ENTRY aparezca el 2º valor de una de las columnas de mi tabla.
Envio:

1. los campos de mi tabla

```html
public class RosterPartido1:BaseViewModel
    {
        [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
        public int IdRoster { get; set; }
        public int DorsalRoster { get; set; }
        public string JugadorRoster { get; set; }
        
    }
```

2. programacion con "firstordefault" (que funciona perfecto pero, claro, busco el 2º valor)

```html
private async void BtnPizarra_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var listadoRoster = await App.SQLiteBD.GetRosterAsync();
            var jugadorUnico = listadoRoster.OrderBy(o => o.DorsalRoster).Select(s => s.JugadorRoster);
            entry.Text = jugadorUnico.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

3. Lo he intentado con "skip" y "take", pero en el ENTRY me escribe lo siguiente: "system linq enumerable......."

```html
private async void BtnPizarra_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var listadoRoster = await App.SQLiteBD.GetRosterAsync();
            var jugadorUnico = listadoRoster.OrderBy(o => o.DorsalRoster).Select(s => s.JugadorRoster);
            TxtSistema.Text = jugadorUnico.Skip(1).Take(1).ToString();
        }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

resolví mi problema con este codigo:

```
private async void BtnPizarra_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        var listadoRoster = await App.SQLiteBD.GetRosterAsync();
        var jugadorUnico = listadoRoster.OrderBy(o => o.DorsalRoster).Select(s => s.JugadorRoster).ToList();
        TxtSistema.Text = jugadorUnico[1]
    }
```

Un saludo